# Android Layout Folder Overridden

Tags: android, layout, overriding, directory

I have placed my constant file in **values-xhdpi** and **values-w768dp** …..

And working on **Nexus 4** (**768x1184**)

```
but it taking resource from **values-xhdpi** only instead of **values-w768dp** which is most generic for it.

In addition with that is it proper naming convention **values-w768dp-h1184dp**
```

Please get me rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources folders (like `values-hdpi`, `values-xhdpi`, etc.) are working with resolution based on `Density-independent pixel` - `dp` (`dpi`). And the qualifier `-wXXXdp` is based on device width in `dp`.

The resolution of your device you based on is represented in actual pixels but not in `dp`.
And just in case: 1184=1280-96, where 96px is a height of  a navigation bar.

Screen density of Nexus 4 is `320` PPI, which corresponds to `values-xhdpi`.

Read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to get a better understanding of a difference between `px` and `dp`.

[This part](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) will be especially helpful for you.

Comment: @@Ivan, thank you very much for assisting me. This time I created a folder with name values-w384dp (768px = 384dp) and its working fine. But still I am having one more anxiety why values-w384dp-h592dp (768x1184px == 384x592dp) is not working ?

Comment: @Amit you have to use `-hdpi`, `-xhdpi`, etc. qualifiers. They were created to handle a wider variety of devices. Using something like `w384dp` is a very bad approach. It just kills all Android Dev principles. It won't work even on a device with width = `385dp` or `383dp` p.s. you have to convert not `768px1184px` but `768x1280px`

Comment: @Amit well, you can accept my answer as a correct one

Comment: @@Ivan, I accepted your answer. But then again please consider a scenario where I having 3 devices say 768x1184 (Nexus 4), 720x1184 (GenyMotion Nexus) and 720x1280 (Samsung GT-I9300) all are having DPI-320 means all take their assets from X-HDPI folder than how I write a layout which is working on all three ?

Comment: @Admit maybe, if you share the layout concept, I could help you. Because, I can't imagine any reason for you to use 3 different layouts in this case. Resolution  difference in 100 pixels is unobservable on 5" display with such high pixel density. That means, that you can consider these 3 resolutions as equal.

Comment: _@Ivan, I create some tool tip using Toast (in CountDownTimer) and placed it over a ImageButton. For that I need exact xco and yco location. Anyway I have done with it; I create some constants in Code (Java file) and for the next time I'll take care of your suggestion...that I should code in a generic way :)